# Get only immediate children (and not grandchildren) of a hierarchical custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, children

Say, for example, I have the following custom taxonomy:

```
Term 1
   Term 1.1
   Term 1.2
      Term 1.2.1
      Term 1.2.2
   Term 1.3
Term 2
   Term 2.1
```

How can I get the children terms of Term 1, not including grandchildren? That is, I want my results to include only Term 1.1, Term 1.2, and Term 1.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possibly with `get_terms()` and the `'parent'` parameter: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Bueno. I was thinking of it backwards :) Thank you!